# Azure CI pipeline not putting Razor Class Library static web assets into the correct folder

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, nuget, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to build a NuGet package that will contain a lot of boilerplate code for an Asp.Net Core web app. As part of this I need to have access to some static web assets (.js, .css files...). When I package the NuGet package on my local PC, the package is created with the static web assets in the correct folder (/staticwebassets/), but when the Azure CI pipeline is run the package is created with the static files in the /content/wwwroot/ folder.

I've tried setting the wwwroot files and folders to both Content and Embedded Resource in Visual Studio and neither seems to make a difference.

Below is a sample of the log output from the Azure DevOps CI log.

```
2023-02-10T15:49:19.5490937Z Add file 'D:\a\1\s\src\Package.Name\wwwroot\js\site.js' to package as 'content\wwwroot\js\site.js'
```

For reference, here's the csproj file for the Razor Class Library:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <RootNamespace>Package.Name</RootNamespace>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
        <GenerateMvcApplicationPartsAssemblyAttributes>true</GenerateMvcApplicationPartsAssemblyAttributes>
        <RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>
        <IncludeRazorContentInPack>false</IncludeRazorContentInPack>
        <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
        <EnableDefaultRazorGenerateItems>true</EnableDefaultRazorGenerateItems>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
        <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\img\" />
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\lib\js-cookie\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="IronPdf" Version="2023.1.11416" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="3.1.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.21.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerBI.Api" Version="3.17.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Select2.js" Version="4.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.21.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="5.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <StaticWebAssetBasePath>_content/$(PackageId)</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I've tried without the StaticWebAssetBasePath property being set as well.

I know we need to update to .Net 6, and we do have a ticket to do this, but I can't do it right now.